# Javascript regex match only words starting with a specific special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match only words starting with # in javascript, for eg. in the following sample text, only **#these** should match.

> I need to match only words like #these.
>   Ignore the ones like @#this , !#this and in#ignore.

The closer I got is here,

```
/(\B(#[a-z0-9])\w+)/gi
```

Ref: https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/114

Comment: Use a whitespace boundary  - [`/(?:^|\s)(#[a-z0-9]\w+)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/pXc3EA/1).

Comment: sorry i misread the question, will update this comment

Comment: Using whitespace boundary almost works, but I'm wondering if there is something more perfect as I'm using the pattern to search and replace html

Comment: `[ ]#these` = whitelist (space) **or** `[^@!a-z]#these` = blacklist (@, !, a-z)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a whitespace  boundary `(?:^|\s)`:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|\s)(#[a-z0-9]\w*)/gi;
var s = "I need to match only words like #these. \nIgnore the ones like @#this , !#this and in#ignore.";
var m, res=[];
while (m = rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

**Details**:

- `(?:^|\s)` - matches the start of string or whitespace
- `(#[a-z0-9]\w*)` - Group 1 (`m[1]`): a `#`, then an alphanumeric char followed with 0 or more word chars (letters, digits, `_` symbols).

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pXc3EA/2), pay attention to what texts are *captured*, rather to the whole matches.

Or trimming each match:

```js
var rx = /(?:^|\s)(#[a-z0-9]\w*)/gi;
var s = "I need to match only words like #these. \nIgnore the ones like @#this , !#this and in#ignore.";
var results = s.match(rx).map(function(x) {return x.trim();}); // ES5
// var results = s.match(rx).map(x => x.trim()); // ES6
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Using whitespace boundary works, but is there any perfect solution for this? :) Thanks!

Comment: What is the criterion for "perfect"? Only match these "#these" if not preceded with the *exact symbols*?

Comment: Perfect == get rid of the space in the beginning of the match.  Thanks!

Comment: You already got it - grab the captured group 1. I think it is the cleanest way. Of course, you may just trim each match if you like.

Comment: Once the [lookbehind](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind) is finally supported in all browsers, you will be able to use `s.match(/(?<!\S)#[a-z0-9]\w*/ig)`. Watch [this table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/). Right now, it only supported in Chrome and Node if the "Experimental Javascript features" flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

Why not search start or with space before. see [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/115) `/ #|^#`

Comment: Using whitespace boundary almost works, but I'm just wondering if there is something more perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I little bit changed your regex to get what do you want.

```
var p = "I need to match only words like #these. Ignore the ones like @#this , !#this and in#ignore."

[^@!a-z$]\#[a-z]+
```

That will be match only #these, you can exclude whatever you don't want by adding between first square bracket

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```js
txt = "I need to match only words like #these. Ignore the ones like @#this , !#this and in#ignore."

console.log(/(^|\s)(#+\w+)/g.exec(txt))
```